# Crop Video to the Closest "Standard" Aspect Ratio/Resolution

Tags: video, ffmpeg, crop

Have an app using ffmpeg to encode videos that are uploaded and am finding a lot of a-typical resolutions are being submitted.  Currently the app is made to handle 16:9, 9:16, 1:1, 4:5 or 4:3.

Looking to give them the option to auto-crop their video to 16:9. 1:1, 9:16, 4:3 or 4:5 depending on which of these their current video is closest to.

Any thoughts on the easiest way to first determine which of these resolutions their current video is closest to and then convert their current video to that res/aspect?

Possibly there is a filter_complex chain that could do this?

Comment: You could always simply refuse content from people who haven't learned to hold their phone horizontally ;-)) [sorry, not helpful, I know]

Comment: LOL.  Well, that is what I have been doing... But, not working too well. :) @Tetsujin

Comment: ffmpeg can't do this automatically. A tedious ugly expression for crop could probably do this,